# Gradle sign with gpg is giving a bad jar signature

Tags: gradle, gnupg, sign

I am trying to publish a jar to Maven Central. I am following instructions in [Sonatype](https://central.sonatype.org/publish/requirements/gpg/#listing-keys)

So... I am trying to test that code-signing works. I am using Gradle. This is my Gradle file:

```groovy
task javadocJar(type: Jar) {
    classifier = 'javadoc'
    from javadoc
}

task sourcesJar(type: Jar) {
    classifier = 'sources'
    from sourceSets.main.allSource
}


signing {
    sign configurations.archives
}

plugins.withId("com.github.johnrengelman.shadow"){

    //this block requires the java plugin to be applied first.
    plugins.withId("java"){

        shadowJar {
            //We are overriding the default jar to be the shadow jar
            classifier = null
            exclude 'META-INF'
            exclude 'META-INF/*.INF'
            exclude 'META-INF/license/*'
        }

        jar {
            manifest {
                attributes(
                        'Built-By'       : System.properties['user.name'],
                        'Build-Timestamp': new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ").format(new Date()),
                        'Created-By'     : "Gradle ${gradle.gradleVersion}",
                        'Build-Jdk'      : "${System.properties['java.version']} (${System.properties['java.vendor']} ${System.properties['java.vm.version']})",
                        'Build-OS'       : "${System.properties['os.name']} ${System.properties['os.arch']} ${System.properties['os.version']}"
                )
            }
        }

        tasks.build.dependsOn tasks.shadowJar
        tasks.shadowJar.mustRunAfter tasks.jar
        tasks.shadowJar.mustRunAfter tasks.javadocJar
        tasks.shadowJar.mustRunAfter tasks.sourcesJar
    }
}

artifacts {
    archives javadocJar, sourcesJar
}
```

When I run `gradle clean build` I am getting some artifacts in my `build/libs` directory. I am using `gpg` to verify them.

I find that the signatures for the `javadoc` and `sources` jar are fine, but the `jar` signature fails validation.

```
$ gpg --verify build/libs/mask-json-field-transform-0.1-javadoc.jar.asc
gpg: assuming signed data in 'build/libs/mask-json-field-transform-0.1-javadoc.jar'
gpg: Signature made Fri Jan  6 17:17:16 2023 PST
gpg:                using EDDSA key Fxxxx9
gpg: Good signature from "Feroze Daud <xxx@yyy.com>" [ultimate]

$ gpg --verify build/libs/mask-json-field-transform-0.1-sources.jar.asc
gpg: assuming signed data in 'build/libs/mask-json-field-transform-0.1-sources.jar'
gpg: Signature made Fri Jan  6 17:17:16 2023 PST
gpg:                using EDDSA key Fxxxx9
gpg: Good signature from "Feroze Daud <xxx@yyy.com>" [ultimate]

$ gpg --verify build/libs/mask-json-field-transform-0.1.jar.asc
gpg: assuming signed data in 'build/libs/mask-json-field-transform-0.1.jar'
gpg: Signature made Fri Jan  6 17:17:16 2023 PST
gpg:                using EDDSA key Fxxxx9
gpg: BAD signature from "Feroze Daud <xxx@yyy.com>" [ultimate]
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I don't think that the `build` task will generate signatures (by default). Perhaps the jar is changing (even if it's only the timestamps of the files)? You might want to try configuring [reproducible builds](https://docs.gradle.org/7.6/userguide/working_with_files.html#sec:reproducible_archives). What happens if you publish the project to Maven Local, or (this is my preference) a local directory [(see example 5)](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html#publishing_maven:repositories)? That should compute fresh signatures.

Comment: Enabling reproducible builds fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I enable reproducible builds, this problem goes away.